# Updating disk size in compute engine does not update size in vm instance

Tags: virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

I had a 50gb disk for my vm instance and I went to the disks in compute engine and changed to size to 100gb.

I restarted my server twice now and it is still showing the disk as only 50gb

Is there some form of delay associated with changing the disk size?

Here is an image of what it looks like on the Google Cloud Console
[image]

Here is an image of what it says on the server
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the size of the physical disks associated with your Compute Engine VM instance doesn't change the usage of that disk without first performing some additional steps.  These steps change the partitioning of the disks.

Recipes for both Linux and Windows can be found in the documentation:

[Resizing the file system and partitions on a zonal persistent disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#resize_partitions)

Comment: For Windows, you need additional manual steps. For supported Linux distributions, Google has built-in tools that resize the boot disk on startup. I wrote a detailed article on how this is done for Debian. https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-debian-9-resize-root-file-system/